# Why does an invalid system time cause a SSL-webapplication to fail?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl, ssl-certificate, internet-explorer, windows-8

Question:
We have a asp.net login page (SSL), with username and password.
You enter them, you click ok, if the credentials are OK, you get redirected to the navigation page.
If the credentials are incorrect, you get redirected to the login page, with a box appearing "username or password incorrect".

Now we just tested IE 10 on our 10 demo servers.
It worked everywhere, except on 2 (the database and software is on the same version everywhere).

On two of the 10 servers, when you login using a correct password and username, 
you get redirected to the login page without a username and password incorrect error instead of the navigation page.
I tested for almost 45 minutes, and found out that the reason the 2 projects didn't work (which are on the same server),
but on a different server than the other 8 that worked, is that the system time on the windows 8 machine with IE 10 was one day into the future.

What kind of setting in the SSL settings/certificate could be the reason for the different behaviour on the two servers ?
And why does it show the login page (already SSL) but not the navigation page ?

And why does the webapplication fail, and not the connection to the site ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing authentication against Active Directory, the date being off would cause the authentication request to fail.  This would be exclusive of the SSL cert.  You should also see some complaints on the machine with the incorrect time in the event log.

I can't comment on your webapplication and how it works.  You'd probably need to go back to the dev and ask them.  Though you shoudl be able to look in the IIS logs and see whats going on in there as well when the user attempts to authenticate in.